# hibernate ddl-auto=update for indexed column("bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0") result in reset of data to 0

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, bit

- MySQL Version = 5.5.51
- SpringBoot Version = 1.2.8.RELEASE
- mysql-connector-java = 5.1.36

### Given:

I have an entity which has an index on a column(`deliveryIndicator`) whose data type is `"bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"`.

I have set `ddl-auto` to `update` in my application.properties like this:

```
        spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

### When

When I ran my application

### Then

JPA reset the all the data for the `deliveryIndicator`  column to `0`.

`Note: other index column data are not resetting.`

## My entity is defined like this

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Office",
            indexes = {@Index(name = "geo_index", columnList = "latitude,longitude"),
            @Index(name = "deliveryIndicator", columnList = "deliveryIndicator")})
    public class Office {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "longitude")
        private Double longitude;

        @Column(name = "latitude")
        private Double latitude;

        @Column(name = "parkingIndicator", columnDefinition = "bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
        private boolean parkingIndicator;

        @Column(name = "disabilityIndicator", columnDefinition = "bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
        private boolean disabilityIndicator;

        @Column(name = "deliveryIndicator", columnDefinition = "bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
        private boolean deliveryIndicator;
        }
```

## Now, I have tried following to fix it:

Removed the index on `deliveryIndicator`.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Office",
            indexes = {@Index(name = "geo_index", columnList = "latitude,longitude")})
    public class Office {....}
```

After this when I ran the application (after bringing back the DB to the previous state) the `deliveryIndicator` column data was not effected/resetted.

## My query is :

- Why this is happening.
- Is there any other solution for this.